# Commerce Kickstart product sub-categories

Tags: commerce

When you set up product category taxonomy items, it seems that subcategories are not supported. If your product is in a subcategory, it doesn't show up when you choose the main category from the main menu on the front page.

i.e., lets say I added a category of 'Computers' and Subcategories of Desktops, Laptops, Games, and Accessories. How do you display those subcategories?

Would it be better to just use the commerce module, or are these systems simply not powerful enough to manage product category depth greater than one level? So in this case, the whole product category menu would be filled with 100 different categories... It just doesn't seem like a realistic approach.

There are always subcategories, unless you sell items as simple as t-shirts, shoes, and gadgets. You could never have :

'Footware' and then subcategories of sneakers, casual, sandals, and dress shoes, etc, etc.

Tops and subcategories of t-shirts, long sleeved shirts, sweatshirts...etc..

I think you get the idea. This drupal 'starter project' isn't a pro solution, is it?

So, can I extend it to show, organize, and sell those subcategories?

[EDIT!]

Wait! I think I figured it out - you can impose hierarchical structure through the Collection product category taxonomy!

I will play for a bit and update with results. Things are looking a bit brighter...

So, I just didn't understand how things were organized.

Collection is the parent Category
Category is the sub category - or whatever single level taxonomy you choose

These must be fields in your Content Type
Then the 'variable' portion (like color) goes in the Product Variation for that selection of the Collection & Category

Seems to work